# How to have two columns(One with a form and One with a image) of bootstrap row to be of same height, and responsive too

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two bootstrap columns, One has a form, another has image. The image division is set to 100% width, Which when resizing the screen, gets responsive. But the form stands to be in same height irrespective of screen size.

[image]

Please refer the below code

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-page-contents">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="headingdescription" style="padding-left:0px;text-align:left">Request a Office space</p>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px">
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Full Name " />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Job Title" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Phone Number" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px">
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Business Name" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Zipcode" />
      </div>
      <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Message" style="height: 100px !important" /> <br> <br>
      <button class="actionbuttons" href="">SUBMIT REQUEST</button> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600/f0d/&text=illo.png" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: what do you expect for layout for the form ? to be 100vh of height  once stack over the image ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I expect the height the form column varies in accordance with the height of the image in right column. But, Now the height of the form column is same irrespective of screen size.

Comment: okay, turn your div into a form tag (which is missing here) , but content will still be stuck at top left . `<div class="row">
    <form class="col-md-6">form content </form> <div class="col-md-6"> img </div>`

Comment: what's the ratio/size of your image ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I changed that, Thanks. Can you help me in having the image of the right to vertically align to bottom ?

Comment: My image is 600*600.

Comment: you may add the class mt-auto to the col hlding the img, if i understand correctly

Comment: @G-Cyr PLease refer the screenshot image in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with Bootstrap but there are 3 problems to overcome:

1. the image must be 100% of it's parent height but must not **affect** it's parent column height. **Solution:** make it a **background** image:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 image-col">

<style>
  .row .image-col {
    background-image: url(url(http://dummyimage.com/600/f0d/&text=illo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position: center right;
  }
</style>
```

2. when the window is less than medium (<768px) the image will wrap underneath the form and it's height will collapse. **Solution:** set an image height for that case with a media query:

```
/* small screens (the default) */
<style>
  .row .image-col {
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/600/f0d/&text=illo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 20rem;    /* image height when image wraps underneath form */
    background-position: center right;
  }

  /* medium and greater screens */  
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .row .image-col:last-child { 
      background-size: auto 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
</style>
```

3. For small screens (less than medium, when the image wraps below the form), we need both columns to be 100% wide.  So we need to specify that with bootstrap by adding class `col-sm-12` to both columns.

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/b02wmy4r/45/).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you wish to see image be aligned to bottom of the form when becoming smaller. You can align the column itself with the class `mt-auto` (margin-top: auto).

Demo:

```css
form {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="text-page-contents">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col-md-6 mt-auto ">
      <p class="headingdescription" style="padding-left:0px;text-align:left">Request a Office space</p>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px">
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Full Name " />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Job Title" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Phone Number" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px">
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Business Name" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Zipcode" />
      </div>
      <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Message" style="height: 100px !important" /> <br> <br>
      <button class="actionbuttons" href="">SUBMIT REQUEST</button> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-auto">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600/f0d/&text=illo.png" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**, the class `align-items-end` on parent is also good to align both columns to bottom.

```css
form {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="text-page-contents">
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <form class="col-md-6 ">
      <p class="headingdescription" style="padding-left:0px;text-align:left">Request a Office space</p>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px">
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Full Name " />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Job Title" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Phone Number" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px">
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Business Name" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Zipcode" />
      </div>
      <input class="formtextarea" placeholder="Message" style="height: 100px !important" /> <br> <br>
      <button class="actionbuttons" href="">SUBMIT REQUEST</button> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600/f0d/&text=illo.png" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I think we're narrowing down, Please refer the image, When I resize the page. There is a empty space left below the form in left col which doesn't look good.

Comment: @DurairajSaravanan did you run the snippet in fullpage and resized the browser, adding the class `mt-auto`, the empty space shows up at the top . Else i totally misunderstand :) (updated both columns with the class)

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the form to resize somehow to be the same height of the image this will not happen.

The reason for the image to behave responsively is that it has an aspect ratio. That means, it has its own native height and width. What you are doing here is to set just the width, and because the aspect ratio, the image height adjusts accordingly.

Form elements have a fixed size by default. They are not supposed to scale like images.

What you can do instead is to set a width of 100% on the inputs and let the width be determined by the width of the parent container. However this will not affect the height of the form elements in any way.

The css for that looks like this:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    /*you also need to change box-sizing,
    since the input itself already has a padding
    and a border and would exceed the boundaries
    of the parent container because of that:*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Note that I have used `[type="text"]`. This selector will only work if you set the type text on your inputs as well like this:

```
<input type="text" class="formtextarea" placeholder="Business Name">
```

If you want your layout to adjust according to the width or height of your screen, I suggest you have a look at media queries in css.

Comment: Yeah, You're right, Image is responsive by aspect ratio and we cant expect same with form. Thanks for you time, Cheers